# Node.js NET concatenate chunked XML data

Tags: xml, node.js, sockets, soap

I am receiving XML/SOAP through a NET socket in Node. The larger SOAP responses are chunked so i need to concatenate the SOAP envelope before i pass it to the XML parser.

Here is the attempt so far

```
//client.net.setEncoding('utf8');
var data = '';
client.net.on('data', function(response) {
    var read = response.toString();
    console.log("READING == "+read);
    if (read.substr(read.length-15) === "</env:Envelope>") {
        if(data.length > 0) {
            /* soap envelope is finally complete, pass to xml parser */
            parser.parseString(data += response);
            data = '';
        }
        /* soap envelope is complete, pass to xml parser */
        parser.parseString(response);
    } else {
        /* not soap response */
        if (read.substr(0, 4) === "HTTP") return;
        /* add chunck to data */
        data += response;
    }
});
```

The incoming data looks like (these are small responses)

```
READING == HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type:application/soap+xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length:644


READING == <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><env:Header><n:Response x
mlns:n="http://www.example.com/" env:role="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/role/ultimateReceiver" env:mustUnderst
and="true">SetTrackingFrequency</n:Response></env:Header><env:Body><n:ResponseSetTrackingFrequency xmlns:n="http://www.example.com/ipr
s/gps/soap"><n:Status>none</n:Status><n:ApplicationID>18</n:ApplicationID><n:RequestID>0</n:RequestID><n:FrequencySecs>0</n:FrequencySecs><n
:ExpirationSecs>0</n:ExpirationSecs></n:ResponseSetTrackingFrequency></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

When the envelope is not complete i am merging the chunks.

This appears to nearly work, except the parser starts to throw error.

```
error: uncaughtException: Text data outside of root node.
```

**Edit - further info**

This code gives the error, but passing same response?

```
client.net.on('data', function(response) {
    var read = response.toString();
    if (read.substr(read.length-15) === "</env:Envelope>") {
        parser.parseString(response);
        return;
    }
}
```

This code gives no error

```
client.net.on('data', function(response) {
        parser.parseString(response);
        return;
}
```

**Full error:**

```
2015-11-13T19:34:50.355Z - error: uncaughtException: Text data outside of root node.
Line: 0
Column: 1228
Char: H date=Fri Nov 13 2015 19:34:50 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), pid=25712, uid=null, gid=null, cwd=C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4 -of
, execPath=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe, version=v4.1.1, argv=[C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe, C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4 -of\i
ndex.js], rss=44589056, heapTotal=34005760, heapUsed=21471184, loadavg=[0, 0, 0], uptime=954829.8959002, trace=[column=10, file=-of\node_mod
ules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js, function=error (C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4, line=666, method=null, native=false, column=7, f
ile=-of\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js, function=strictFail (C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4, line=692, method=null, nati
ve=false, column=15, file=-of\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js, function=Object.write (C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4, lin
e=1035, method=write (C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4, native=false, column=31, file=-of\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js, function=Parse
r.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4, line=497, method=exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (C:\Users\v_lowe\
Dropbox\nodejs\v4, native=false, column=59, file=-of\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js, function=Parser.parseString (C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox
\nodejs\v4, line=7, method=parseString (C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4, native=false, column=12, file=-of\lib\gps_parse.js, function=Sock
et.<anonymous> (C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4, line=41, method=<anonymous> (C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4, native=false, column=13,
file=events.js, function=emitOne, line=77, method=null, native=false, column=7, file=events.js, function=Socket.emit, line=169, method=emit,
 native=false, column=16, file=_stream_readable.js, function=readableAddChunk, line=146, method=null, native=false, column=10, file=_stream_
readable.js, function=Socket.Readable.push, line=110, method=Readable.push, native=false], stack=[Error: Text data outside of root node., Li
ne: 0, Column: 1228, Char: H,     at error (C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4 -of\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:666:10),
   at strictFail (C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4 -of\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:692:7),     at Object.write (C:\User
s\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4 -of\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:1035:15),     at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (C:
\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4 -of\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:497:31),     at Parser.parseString (C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4
-of\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:7:59),     at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\v_lowe\Dropbox\nodejs\v4 -of\lib\gps_parse.js:41:12),     a
t emitOne (events.js:77:13),     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7),     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16),     at Socket.Reada
ble.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by looking for the end pattern instead of using the beginning, essentially :

- Accumulate data in a buffer each time it is received
- Each time data is appended to buffer, check for end pattern in the updated buffer
- As long as the end pattern is found in the buffer :

  - Chop a segment from start until the first end pattern, this is your frame!
  - Go ahead and parse/process that frame. Be sure to remove it from the buffer.
  - Continue chopping the buffer if it still contains end pattern, else let it grow

That’s all!

```
var textBuffer = '';
var parseFrame = function (str){};

function processChunk (chunk) {
  var segments, frame;
  var startChar = String.fromCharCode(1);
  var endChar = String.fromCharCode(0);

  // having no endChar will skip the loop,
  // but we still save the chunk
  textBuffer += chunk;

  while (textBuffer && textBuffer.indexOf(endChar) !== -1) {
    // use endChar in lieu of startChar so we don’t
    // miss a chunk without beginning
    segments = textBuffer.split(endChar);

    // first chunk we extract may or may not have a startChar
    // replace() will have no effect if startChar is absent
    frame = segments.shift().replace(startChar, '');

    // if join() results in '', endChar won’t be found,
    // and we will get out of loop
    textBuffer = segments.join(endChar);

    // beware: it is possible that the frame
    // is incomplete if we *never* got the startChar,
    // the next chunks will be OK though
    try { parseFrame(frame); }
    catch (err) { console.log(err); }
  }
}
```